# Is there any encoding scheme that is resilient to double encoding?

Tags: encoding

Is there any encoding scheme that is resilient to double (or more) encodes or decodes and also safe against XSS and SQL injection attacks?
To illustrate:

```
enc(A) --> A'
enc(A') --> A'
```

and subsequently:

```
dec(A') --> A
dec(A) --> A
```

Where this would be useful is in a MVC framework, where we specify the content be encoded prior to being sent to the Controller. Howerver, the UI is multiple layers and may (inadvertently) double encode by both the subview and its parent.

Comment: And how is this related to IT Security?

Comment: Added a bit more info...

Comment: Have you actually searched through the website before asking this question? We have numerous answers on how to sanitize input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such function exists that is useful. You want a function `enc : X → Y` and `dec : Y → X` so that

```
∀ x ∈ X: dec(enc(x)) = x
```

(that is, `dec` is the inverse of `enc`),

with the additional constraint that

```
∀ x ∈ X : dec(enc(enc(x))) = x
```

Therefore, `X = Y` and `enc(x) = x`!

The `enc` and `dec` functions are *the same*, and are the *unit function* (the function that returns its input):

```
enc(x) = x
dec = enc
```

---

What does this mean in practical terms? Let's assume we have an escaping scheme that backslashes the forbidden characters `'` and `\`. So we have

```
enc( 'foo\ )   = \'foo\\
```

Now let's assume the user inputs a string `\'foo\\`, then the escaped output should be

```
enc( \'foo\\ ) = \\\'foo\\\\
```

Which is the same result as `enc(enc( 'foo\ ))`.

There is no way to tell for this function whether it is an output of `enc` or not.

This changes when `X ≠ Y` (i.e. the output of `enc` has a different type than unencoded input). Let us define a polymorphic `enc` like so:

```
enc : X → Y | Y → Y
dec : Y → X
∀ x ∈ X : dec(enc(x))      = x
∀ x ∈ X : dec(enc(enc(x))) = x
∀ y ∈ Y : enc(y) = y
```

In most programming languages, this could be implemented with object orientation:

```
class Str {
  method enc() : EncodedStr { some encoding code }
}
class EncodedStr {
  method enc() : EncodedStr { return self } // the unit function
  method dec() : Str        { some decoding code }
}
```

That is, `∀ x ∈ Str : x.enc.enc.dec = x` etc..

The abstract concepts of this answer can be summarized as

> You simply have to remember if you already encoded that input or not.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding shouldn't impact the security of a properly developed application.  At the time of use,  the data should always made safe.  The only time encoding becomes a problem in security is if a escape routine is run,  and then a decoding (or perhaps an encoding) routine is run and then a sensitive function is invoked with this data.  In this case,  a decode routine will always undermine the escape routine.

For example,  the following is always insecure:

```
mysql_query("select * from user where id ='"+urldecode(addslashes($_GET[id]))+"'")
```

In this case, paramaterization insures that regardless of how the variable is encoded,  the resulting sting is what is expected.   If you always escape immediately before use,  then encoding will never be a problem.